# Удаление таблицы pgsql через командную строку

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я пытаюсь удалить таблицу в pgsql через командную строку, но она не удаляется

testdb=# DROP TABLE publisher
testdb-# \dt+

| Схема | Имя | Тип | Владелец | Хранение | Метод доступа | Размер | Описание |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | publisher | таблица | postgres | постоянное | heap | 8192 bytes |  |

Но после того как я в интерфейсе pgadmin4 выполняю ту же команду, всё удаляется

testdb-# \dt+
Отношения не найдены.

В чем причина, что я не могу удалить таблицу через командную строку?

Comment: ; в конце не хватает?

Comment: Для правильного форматирования добавляйте пустые строки перед и после таблицы. Это давний баг SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В терменале В linux так:

```
sudo -iu postgres psql -p <node_port> -c "\c <db_name>; DROP TABLE publisher;"
```

Смею предположить что в windows что-то типа:

```
<postgres_bin_folder>\\psql -iu postgres -p <node_port> -c "\c <db_name>; DROP TABLE publisher;"
```

Это удалит Вашу таблицу без необходимости ручного входа в psql. Вместо <node_port> введите порт, куда развернули postgres. <db_name> - имя вашей базы данных

Comment: ответ в текущем виде попросту неверен из-за того, что в postgresql в принципе не существует команды USE

Comment: @Мелкий. Да, Вы правы. Исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Да в конце не хватало точки с запятой.
Когда вы добавляете ; в командной строке, вы, вероятно, сталкиваетесь с ошибкой, потому что символ ; в Windows командной строке используется как разделитель команд, и командная строка пытается выполнить каждую команду по отдельности.

В случае PostgreSQL (и других СУБД) символ ; используется для завершения SQL-запроса. В командной строке psql или других SQL-клиентах, вы должны вводить SQL-запрос целиком и нажимать Enter, чтобы запрос был отправлен на выполнение. SQL-клиент сам поймет, что команда закончилась и выполнит её.